# Using Faraday to make HTTP requests over a Unix socket

Tags: ruby, faraday, unix-socket

I tried putting together a custom Faraday adapter to make HTTP requests using a Unix socket using NetX::HTTPUnix. The code looks like this:

```
module Faraday
  class Adapter
    class NetHttpUnix < Faraday::Adapter::NetHttp
      def perform_request(http, env)
        if :get == env[:method] and !env[:body]
          # prefer `get` to `request` because the former handles gzip (ruby 1.9)
          http.get env[:url], env[:request_headers]
        else
          http.request create_request(env)
        end
      end

      def create_request(env)
        request = Net::HTTPGenericRequest.new \
          env[:method].to_s.upcase,    # request method
          !!env[:body],                # is there request body
          :head != env[:method],       # is there response body
          "/",                   # request uri path (i'm just hard coding / because URI::Generic doesn't have a uri_path method
          env[:request_headers]        # request headers

        if env[:body].respond_to?(:read)
          request.body_stream = env[:body]
        else
          request.body = env[:body]
        end
        request
      end


      def net_http_connection(env)
        socket = env[:url].to_s
        NetX::HTTPUnix.new(socket)
      end
    end
  end
end

Faraday::Adapter.register_middleware net_http_unix: Faraday::Adapter::NetHttpUnix
```

However, when I try making a request with this adapter, I get a Faraday::ConnectionError. When I look at the exception backtrace I see that the code is attempting to open a TCP socket in http.rb.

Does there exist a Faraday adapter already that works with Unix sockets? I don't want to reinvent the wheel here.

Comment: If you're going to split arguments up over several lines use the regular brackets `(...)` to encapsulate those. The backslash here is highly irregular.

Answer (score 0):

After much looking around, the above code is actually perfectly fine!

I was having problems because of how Ruby's `URI.parse` works. My URI was in the form of `unix:///path/to/socket`, which `URI.parse` parses to `unix:/path/to/socket`, which Net::Http::Unix in turn didn't parse as a Unix socket URL, because it expects a Unix socket URI to begin with `unix://`.

The solution ended up being to use five slashes in my path, like so: `unix://///path/to/socket`. When you do this, `URI.parse` parses it to `unix:///path/to/socket`, `net_http_unix` sees that it starts with `unix://` and strips that part off, leaving `/path/to/socket` which we can connect to.

In my case I was specifying an absolute path; if I had been using a relative path I may have been okay with `unix://relative/path/to/socket`.

One caveat about my above code: the 4th argument to `Net::HttpGenericRequest.new` is just "/". That is suitable for me because I'm using RPC over HTTP which never has a relative URI; if you have those in your app or service you'll need a way to take the URI and separate the socket path from the relative path.

Comment: We have two options to fix this: 1) Fix UNIX_REGEXP 
 in https://github.com/puppetlabs/net_http_unix/blob/master/lib/net_x/http_unix.rb - add testing for file:// too or 2) Fix (or monkey patch) URI#to_s because it knows about file:// and postgres:// only - so you could make PR to ruby repo